# Why is there so much "pulling" involved in English driving?

Tags: etymology, terminology

There seems to a variety of terminology around the verb "to pull" in English driving, which always puzzles me. Here are some examples:

- to pull out of/into something: to drive out of/into
- to pull over: (transitive: to stop; especially police, right?)
- to pull in (intransitive: [to arrive at a destination or come to a stop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull%20in))
- to pull away: e.g., [maneuver the vehicle out of its parking spot and resume driving](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43280)

Do these phrases have some (common) historical origin (such as, being pulled by a horse before cars were motorized), or did I miss some very general meaning of "to pull" when learning English?

Comment: [Etymon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pull) only has one expression of this type: 'To pull up "check a course of action" is from 1808, figurative of the lifting of the reins in horse-riding.' But it does mention the link with 'draw', and I think 'draw' works in all your examples.

Comment: Are these terms not used in British English?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Perhaps less so, but they're definitely used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, would you say *draw [the car] into/out of the garage*? It's not at all idiomatic in the US, but maybe in other parts of the English-speaking world it is? I also wouldn't ever say *the police drew me over* etc., but I might possibly say *the car drew away from the curb* (at least it doesn't sound wrong to me).

Comment: Etymon also has "To pull in "arrive" (1892) and pull out "depart" (1868) are from the railroads." As a train consists of an engine pulling carriages, they all have transferred from the railroads.

Comment: 'Drive, draft, and drift' are about being urged (forward), while 'draw, dray and drag' are about being pulled forward.

Comment: Likely this locution came from the time that vehicles were pulled by horses. In the US, we measure engine power by horsepower (each equal to 745.7 watts), and you can still ask "How many horses do you have under the hood?" to inquire about an engine.

Comment: @deadrat  Spot on. Man's reliance on the motor-car is but a blink of the eye when compared to the millennia of the horse when man became dependent on this noble beast to develop economic potential, to wage war and to carry off damsels in distress! Yes, an engine's BHP is a nod to the past!

Comment: My reference to "(American) English" was mostly guesswork. I did not want to imply that this is restricted to American English; this is just where I came across it. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I would guess it's a combo of horsey history and the fact that a car is steered basically by pulling on one part or another of the steering wheel.  The term "pull" is simply intuitive for many actions of driving a car and similar activities.

Comment: @10006a I was saying that there are examples such as _he drew out of/into the lay-by / drew over to the kerb / drew in at the station / drew away from the kerb_ which are all idiomatic, not that 'draw' will work with all similar examples. I suspect that 'pull ...' won't be idiomatic in all cases either: ?/*pull the car into the garage? And note that you, not OP, introduce the direct object [your car] with pull into / out of..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wasn't challenging your assertion, just genuinely curious. You said "I think 'draw' works in all your examples' and I wondered if this is literally true in your dialect. I would definitely say *pull out of/into* (the OP's wording) *the garage*, or *the parking spot*, or similar places where a car might go); I put *the car* in parentheses because I might or might not specify, but would mainly say it of a vehicle. But I would not say *draw out of/into* in similar circumstances. Similarly, I can't make *draw* work in the second example, but that doesn't mean others can't.

Comment: @10006a In my previous comment, I gave particular examples I'm happy with and which occur on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a hang-over from animal-drawn conveyances. The wagon would be pulled in to the side of the road in order to stop within causing obstruction.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster Unabridged, in its **Synonym Discussion** for the verb form of *pull*, notes:

> *draw*, *drag*, *haul*, *hale*, *tug*, *tow*: *pull* is a general term meaning to move in the direction of the person
>   or thing exerting force

It's interesting to note that, seen in this light, the direction you're trying to go is what's exerting the force on your vehicle (e.g. when you're *pulling into traffic*, the traffic is what is supplying the pull; your vehicle has simply latched onto it, metaphorically speaking).

Comment: I can understand how traffic could be pulling. It is moving after all. But how about "we pulled into the parking lot"? I don't fell like the parking lot is pulling at all :)

Comment: I disagree about your pulling into traffic line.  One can be "pulled *along by* the crowd" - in which the crowd is doing the pulling.  But when you "pull into traffic", you are pulling yourself.